# Requiring tensorflow with Python 2.7.11 occurs ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I tried `pip install tensorflow` on OS X El Capitan and it succeeded.
However, if I tried to import tensorflow, ImportError occured.
Please tell me when you know.

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
>>>
```

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same question.
Try to follow the [official instruction] to install tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

```
# Mac OS X
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo easy_install --upgrade six
```

Then, select the correct binary to install:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl

# Mac OS X, GPU enabled, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.4
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.4
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.5
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.5
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v5. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 3.4 or 3.5:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl

# Mac OS X, GPU enabled, Python 3.4 or 3.5:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Install TensorFlow:

```
# Python 2
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Comment: yep, works. amazing. would have wasted a week trying to fix this.