# "No suitable image found" using Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a program from GitHub (https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow) that requires TensorFlow to run, but every time I use TensorFlow (not just this program), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 3, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x03
```

I'm not sure what's going on, how can I fix this so that these programs run properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing Tensorflow from the [instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034570/requiring-tensorflow-with-python-2-7-11-occurs-importerror).

Comment: Now the "image" referenced doesn't exist at all. Sorry if I'm making a stupid mistake, but how could I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you have 2 python installations and it's using the wrong one. Try "which python". Also try a basic test: enter python interpreter. Type "import tensorflow".